# Where can I find a list of bugs in the current release of OS X?

Tags: macos, bug

I thought perhaps [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19599/what-lion-bugs-irritate-you-the-most) would be a list of bugs, but it's been closed.

Is there another place out there where I can find this info? And when I say the *current release* I mean whichever release is current at the time that you're looking for the information.

Comment: That question was closed because "most annoying" is subjective to the individual it affected. One's person's "most annoying bug" is another one's passing shrug. I have updated this question to make it more objective.

Comment: FWIW, http://openradar.appspot.com is a community repository of bugs that have been filed with Apple.

Comment: @Bavarious  Wow, fascinating, thanks for that link!

Comment: I've posted some notes at [Lion ideas - Lri.me](http://cs.helsinki.fi/u/lranta/ideas/lion.html), but they are focused on annoyances more than actual bugs

Comment: Yes Philip, "most annoying" is subjective. But with a voting system, like the one here on stackexchange, subjective answers become more objective as they gain votes.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly Apple does not provide such info and I have never seen any place which systematically compiles user complaints into that kind of list.  So as far as I know, the answer is "no".

Comment: I thought this was as good start, before it got closed: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19599/what-lion-bugs-irritate-you-the-most

Comment: @Arne  If that kind of thing is helpful for you, you could start another question like "What Lion bugs still present in 10.7.1 should Apple give top priority?"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know apple does not publish that information until they implement a fix in an update. At that point they publish what the bug is and how the update plans on fixing the bug.

If Apple published a list of their bugs in the OS, hackers could take advantage of the bug. Only in rare cases are bugs published, but never by OS suppliers. The bugs are published by security firms when the bug is so dangerous the public needs to know of its existence to avoid being hacked.

Most issues with mac are not bugs in the OS but problems due to slight differences between the OS X series. This issue is especially noticeable when compiling code from MacPorts.